# How to mock a helper function in a PrivateObject

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

When testing private methods of a class using visual studio's built-in test tools one creates an instance of PrivateObject like so:

```
PrivateObject classUnderTest = new PrivateObject(typeof(ClassUnderTest);
```

Is it possible to have a method in that PrivateObject return set values for testing purposes like so:

```
classUserTest.getNumberFromFile = 5; // Pseudo-code to have getNumberFromFile() to return 5 when it is called by a another method in the same class
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly. What is the class you want to test and what is the class you would like to mock?